# X11 is not changing taskbar title

Tags: c++, window, x11

I'm trying to change the icon and title of my application but for some reason it doesn't change it on the taskbar only on the winodow

```
Atom NET_WM_NAME = XInternAtom(dpy, "_NET_WM_NAME", False);
Atom NET_WM_ICON_NAME = XInternAtom(dpy, "_NET_WM_ICON_NAME", False);
Atom UTF8_STRING = XInternAtom(dpy, "UTF8_STRING", False);

title = "Title";
XChangeProperty(dpy, win, NET_WM_NAME, UTF8_STRING, 8, PropModeReplace, (unsigned char*) title.c_str(), title.length());
XChangeProperty(dpy, win, NET_WM_ICON_NAME, UTF8_STRING, 8, PropModeReplace, (unsigned char*) title.c_str(), title.length());
```

**[This is what i see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKWQp.png)**

This problem appears only on Ubuntu and not on Arch

Comment: Could it be due to image format, such as RGB with no alpha or something like this ?

Comment: but should at least change the title instead of leaving "unkown"